# Selector for a list-jquery newb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-table

I have a table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item1<td>
        <td><p>Description<p><br><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item2<td>
        <td><p>Description1</p><p>Description2</p><br><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item3<td>
        <td><p>Description3<p><br><td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my javascript to get an array of items

```
var iList = document.querySelectorAll('td:first');
```

and here is to get all mapped `td p` content

```
var iDesc = document.querySelectorAll('td:second p');
```

I would like to create a mapped then sort its content in the onload event by the way. Is what I am doing correct ? I mean the selector `td:first` and second with my example table

In the example above there is one `td` element containing 2 `p`'s

Comment: how to you want to sort it? in what order?

Comment: I want to sort it alphabetically in response to the first selector's node content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run a loop for each tr element and get the keys and values from td elements. Next, push them into an array.

```
var arr = new Array();
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    var key = $row.find('td:first').html();
    var value = $row.find('td:last').html();
    arr.push([key, value]);
});
```

Finally, sort the array by it's first index.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var valueA, valueB;
    valueA = a[0]; // Where 1 is your index, from your example
    valueB = b[0];
    if (valueA < valueB) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (valueA > valueB) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JUTxU/)

Comment: Thank you, now I am stuck at how to put those sorted values back into the table, there is no id in my table, as it is generated from server code

Comment: Do you mean you have to sort map by it's key? I'm checking that too if that's the case.

Comment: @EwrXcerq, i reconstructed the code by using an array. And added sorting function.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-selectors `:first` and `:second` don't exist, (`:first` exist in jQuery but it's not a CSS selector).
Here is [the official list of CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

What you need here is the `:nth-child` pseudo selector :

```
var iList = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(1)');    
var iDesc = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2) p');
```

PS : Pay attention to your code, you don't close `<td>s` but re-open new ones, [`<td>` don't have to be closed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags), which means that in this `<tr>` you have 4 `<td>`s :

```
<tr>
    <td>Item1
    <td>
    <td><p>Description<p><br>
    <td>
</tr>
```

Comment: actually in my real code there are close td's. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: `:nth-child()` is not supported by IE8, so it's better to use `TD:first-child` and `:first-child + TD` instead of `TD:nth-child(1)` and `TD:nth-child(2)` respectively.

Comment: Yep @MaratTanalin, `document.querySelectorAll()` isn't supported by IE7 too. And btw, `:nth-child` works on IE6+ when used with jQuery.

Comment: IE8 has much bigger market share than IE7. IE7 is not important already while IE8 still is. Your answer uses native `querySelectorAll()`, so jQuery is irrelevant here.